# Create a list of start date and end date in python with first day of month and last day of month

Tags: python, list

I need a list of start date end date starting with the first day of month and last day of month.  Output should look like below:

```
    start_date = datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)
    Output:
    2023-01-01 2023-01-31
    2023-02-01 2023-02-28
    2023-03-01 2023-03-31
    2023-04-01 2020-04-30
    2020-05-01 2020-05-31
```

Below is what I tried:

```
 from datetime import datetime
 import datetime

 start_date = datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)
 today= datetime.date.today()

 date_list = []

 def date_range(start_date):
    return [{"startDate": start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
         "endDate": (start_date + 
     datetime.timedelta(days=30.9)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}]

while start_date<today:
    date_list.append(date_range(start_date))
    start_date= (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30.9))

for date_item in date_list:
   date_range = date_item[0]
   startDate = date_range['startDate']
   endDate = date_range['endDate']
   print(startDate,endDate)
```

Thank you

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation. (2) What is wrong with your code (error messages, output)?

Comment: So why the tag Pandas in your question???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2023, 12, 31)

while start_date <= end_date:
    last_day_of_month = datetime.date(start_date.year, start_date.month, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)
    end_date_of_month = last_day_of_month - datetime.timedelta(days=last_day_of_month.day)
    print(start_date, end_date_of_month)
    start_date = end_date_of_month + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Output:

```
2023-01-01 2023-01-31
2023-02-01 2023-02-28
2023-03-01 2023-03-31
2023-04-01 2023-04-30
2023-05-01 2023-05-31
2023-06-01 2023-06-30
2023-07-01 2023-07-31
2023-08-01 2023-08-31
2023-09-01 2023-09-30
2023-10-01 2023-10-31
2023-11-01 2023-11-30
2023-12-01 2023-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
begin = pd.date_range(start_date, today, freq='MS')
end = pd.date_range(start_date, today+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0), freq='M')

dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(sorted([*begin, *end]))
```

Output:

```
>>> dti.to_pydatetime().tolist()
[datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 31, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 28, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 31, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 30, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 31, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Actually I need a list where I can assign start and end date in a loop

Answer (score 0):

For an elegant one-liner (alright I guess its a two-liner) you can do this:

```
import datetime 

year = 2023 

# We create the result by creating an array of subarrays
# the first element is the start of the month (x)
# the second element is the start of the next month (x%12+1) minus 1 day 

result = [ [datetime.datetime(year,x,1), (datetime.datetime(year + int(x/12),(x%12)+1,1)-datetime.timedelta(days=1)) ] for x in list(range(1,13)) ]

# Now we need to print the result in the format you requested 8)
# 'result' is an array of [d1,d2] subarrays, where d1/d2 are date(1/2). 
# to convert this result to the desired text output you can run the following: 

[ print("{} {}".format(d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),d2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))) for [d1,d2] in result ]
```

This will create the following output:

```
2023-01-01 2023-01-31
2023-02-01 2023-02-28
2023-03-01 2023-03-31
2023-04-01 2023-04-30
2023-05-01 2023-05-31
2023-06-01 2023-06-30
2023-07-01 2023-07-31
2023-08-01 2023-08-31
2023-09-01 2023-09-30
2023-10-01 2023-10-31
2023-11-01 2023-11-30
2023-12-01 2023-12-31
```

Thank you for reading this answer... Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The calendar module has some functionality that you may find helpful.

```
from datetime import date
from calendar import monthrange

YEAR = 2023

for month in range(1, 13):
    start = date(YEAR, month, 1)
    end = date(YEAR, month, monthrange(YEAR, month)[1])
    print(start, end)
```

**Output:**

```
2023-01-01 2023-01-31
2023-02-01 2023-02-28
2023-03-01 2023-03-31
2023-04-01 2023-04-30
2023-05-01 2023-05-31
2023-06-01 2023-06-30
2023-07-01 2023-07-31
2023-08-01 2023-08-31
2023-09-01 2023-09-30
2023-10-01 2023-10-31
2023-11-01 2023-11-30
2023-12-01 2023-12-31
```